# Slow add column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an 8 million row table in an RDS mysql instance which is read replicated.
When adding a new column (int / length 2 / default 0) the primary DB reached 100% and hung until reboot.
So, I ran a test on my local machine - same table / same new column (not read replicated) and the change was instant.

Please advise why such an issue would occur? Any ideas welcome

Comment: What is the DB Instance Type of your Amazon RDS database?

Comment: Hi, is a db.m4.xlarge